# Does anyone now how to add an Edge Animate to CS CART?

Tags: adobe-edge

I have created an edge animate and now I am trying to add it to CS CART...Has anyone done this before? I need to know where to place each of the files so that it displays.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this and here it is below.

1 - Upload all images to the images directory.  Just place them in the directory, not a sub folder within

2 - Upload your YOURPROJECT_EDGE.JS file to the root of your store (public_html directory)

3 - Go to  ..../design/themes/responsive/templates/index.tpl

4 - Here you need to add the contents between the  tags

You will need to place this inbetween an {if}{/if} block so that it only applies to the page you want it to.  You will need to wrap the content in literal tags.  My example is below

```
{if $page.page_id == 33}
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    {literal}<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="design/themes/responsive/templates/addons/my_changes/hooks/pages/js/edge_includes/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
<script>
   AdobeEdge.loadComposition('XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX', {
    scaleToFit: "width",
    centerStage: "horizontal",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "1500px",
    width: "1000px",
    height: "2500px"
}, {"style":{"${symbolSelector}":{"isStage":"true","rect":["undefined","undefined","1000px","2500px"],"fill":["rgba(255,255,255,1)"]}},"dom":{}}, {"dom":{}});
</script>{/literal}
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->
{/if}
```

6 - once you have done this go to design/themes/responsive/templates/addons/my_changes/hooks/pages/ and create a page called page_content.override.tpl

7 - create a folder called js and in this upload your edge_includes folder which contains the edge.6.0.0.min.js file.

8 - Go back to your page_content.override.tpl and add in the div that contains your edge project.  The page ID will need to reflect the page id of your own cs cart page.

```
{if $page.page_id == 33}
<style>Any styling here</style>
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-XXXXXXX"></div>
{hook name="pages:page_content"}{/hook}
{/if}
```

You can also add any styling here in between style tags.

Make sure you clear your cahce and it should be working.

Hope this helps someone!!!